# Scaling plots to get same size on same row

Tags: r

I'm trying to reproduce this figure, I'm facing hard times in reproducing two things, the right scale ratio (all plots are square with clear top title and top left corner letter label), the second is I see a gap between the marginal graphs and the plots themselves.
What I want to achieve is this:
[image]

My dataset:

```
structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), turns = c(13L, 16L, 61L, 61L, 95L, 
5L, 33L, 9L, 66L, 119L), victory_status = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("draw", "mate", "outoftime", 
"resign"), class = "factor"), winner = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("charcoal", "cream", 
"draw"), class = "factor"), increment_code = structure(c(3L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10+0", "15+0", 
"15+2", "15+30", "20+0", "30+3", "5+10"), class = "factor"), 
    cream_rating = c(1500L, 1322L, 1496L, 1439L, 1523L, 1250L, 
    1520L, 1413L, 1439L, 1381L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 1261L, 
    1500L, 1454L, 1469L, 1002L, 1423L, 2108L, 1392L, 1209L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the following with great help from @stefan:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gtable)
library(cowplot)
library(gridExtra)

d1<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")

lims <- c(floor(min(d1$cream_rating, d1$charcoal_rating)), ceiling(max(d1$cream_rating, d1$charcoal_rating)))

p.001<- ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = "seagreen4")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(cream = 17, charcoal = 16, draw= 15)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face = "plain", hjust = 0.5), legend.text = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())+guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c(NA, NA, NA)))) 

p.002.a<- ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = "seagreen4")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(cream = 17, charcoal = 16, draw= 15)) +
  ggtitle("Scatter Plot With Marginal Histograms") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face = "plain", hjust = 0.5), legend.text = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())+guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c(NA, NA, NA)))) 
p.002<-
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.002.a+ ggtitle("Scatter Plot With Marginal Histograms") , type = "histogram",
                             margins = 'both',
                             size = 5,
                             groupColour = TRUE,
                             groupFill = TRUE,
                             position = "identity")

p.004a<-ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
geom_density2d(alpha = 0.3, na.rm = TRUE) +
geom_point(alpha = 0, show.legend = FALSE) +
scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "cyan4", charcoal = "peachpuff2", draw = "lightskyblue1")) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(cream = 16, charcoal = 17, draw = 15)) +
xlim(lims) + 
ylim(lims) +
ggtitle("2D-Density Plot with Marginal Density plot") +
xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal")+ theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c(NA, NA, NA)))) +
  theme(legend.text = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())

p.005 <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.004a+ggtitle("2D Density Plot With Marginal Density plot"), d1, type = "density",
                          margins = 'both',
                          size = 5,
                          groupColour = TRUE,
                          groupFill = TRUE,
                          position = "identity"
)

plot_row <- plot_grid(p.001, p.002, p.005, nrow = 1)


final <- plot_grid(
  title, plot_row,
  ncol = 1,
  rel_heights = c(0.5, 0.5)
)

final
```

But I'm getting these figures:

[image]

I don't mind using any function such as grid.arrange or anything that could reproduce the same figure above.

Comment: I couldn't use it since I can't reproduce your code for p0.005, but it might be worth trying [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the plot square use:

```
theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

To fix the gap between the graph and the marginal use:

```
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

instead of

```
theme(legend.text = element_blank())
```

Comment: I tried you adjustment @Almog5690, but it is still showing long plots instead of squares. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry I didn't read the question properly, I thought the problem was in the gap between the main title and the 3 plots. I've edited my answer. hopefully, this will answer your questions.

Comment: Where to add the `theme(aspect.ratio = 1)` @Almog5690? , also can I use a different function that can scale the title on each plot, because the title on each plot seems to stay large and out of scale and part of it disappear when combined cowplot or plot_grid.

Comment: Add it to the plots p.001, p.002.a, p.004a in the plot "theme" or simply use: ```p.001 <- p.001 + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)```.. Regarding the plots titles, my suggestion is to adjust the size of the titles to 10 or 8 in the theme ```plot.title = element_text(size = 10)```.

Comment: p.s.if you want to label your plots you can do so by adding "labels" parameter to the plot_grid function, like so: ```plot_row <- plot_grid(p.001, p.002, p.005, nrow = 1,labels = c("A","B","C"))```

Comment: I just tried it @almog5690, the title adjusted to 8 and it seems to work, but the output missing second figure! can you outline in your answer the command line, I tried: `p.001a <- p.001 + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
p.002a <- p.002 + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
p.003a <- p.003 + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
plot_grid(p.001a, p.002a, p.003a, labels = "AUTO", nrow=1)`

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are run the ```theme(aspect.ratio = 1)``` after the plot is already marginalized. try this: ```p.002a <- ggplot(...)``` then ```p.002a <-p.002a + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)``` and finally ```p.002 = ggmarginal(p.002a + ...)``` and the same for the other plots.

Comment: I tried this `p.002a<-p.002aa +  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
p.002= ggMarginal(p.002a + type = "histogram",  margins = 'both', size = 5, groupColour = TRUE, groupFill = TRUE, position = "identity")
p.002`  it throws me an error `error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:15:33: unexpected '='`

Comment: Its because you used ```+``` instead of ```,``` in the ggmarginal function. this should work: ```ggMarginal(p.002a, type = "histogram", ...)```

Comment: It worked partially @Almog5690, thank you so much! Is there away to scale the plot to a larger size so the title can fit, or make the font adjust when changing the scale? because now even at 8, two figure titles are our of scale!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem, I see all of the titles when I look at the plot on full screen. if this is still a problem for you the only thing I can think of is to display the titles in 2 rows, like so ```ggtitle("first-row \n second-row")```

Comment: I'm wondering how they were able to generate it in the first place! I will keep work on it.